# su -c command fails when running in a script

Tags: bash, unicorn

I am trying to issue a unicorn command via a shell script on a digital ocean ubuntu server. The command is:

```
su - xxx -c cd /home/xxx/apps/app_name && rbenv rehash && rbenv local 2.3.1 && /home/xxx/apps/app_name/bin/unicorn -c /home/xxx/apps/app_name/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

This command works when issued on the command line but if I put it into a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

USER=xxx

APP_ROOT=/home/xxx/apps/app_name
RBENV_RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1

SET_PATH="cd $APP_ROOT && rbenv rehash && rbenv local $RBENV_RUBY_VERSION"
RAILS_ENV=production
UNICORN="$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn"
UNICORN_OPTS="-c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E $RAILS_ENV -D"
CMD="$SET_PATH && $UNICORN $UNICORN_OPTS"

su - $USER -c "$CMD"
```

I get this error: `-su: rbenv: command not found`

If I remove the quotes around `$CMD`, I get this error:`su: invalid option -- 'E'`

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Following the comments below, I have amended the script by adding a path to rbenv like this:

```
RBENV_ROOT="/home/$USER/.rbenv"
SET_PATH="cd $APP_ROOT && $RBENV_ROOT/bin/rbenv rehash && $RBENV_ROOT/bin/rbenv local $RBENV_RUBY_VERSION"
```

When I run this now I get the following error:
`-su: cd /home/xxx/apps/app_name && /home/xxx/.rbenv/bin/rbenv rehash && /home/xxx/.rbenv/bin/rbenv local 2.3.1 && /home/xxx/apps/app_name/bin/unicorn /home/xxx/apps/app_name/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get different results, is that the shell splits the command is actually split into multiply parts:

```
su - xxx -c cd /home/xxx/apps/app_name 
&& rbenv rehash
&& rbenv local 2.3.1 
&& /home/xxx/apps/app_name/bin/unicorn -c /home/xxx/apps/app_name/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

For each newline a new command is called in your shell (As *your* user, not the substituted).

The above means call `su` with `'-' 'xxx' '-c' 'cd' '/home/xxx/apps/app_name'`, if that success then call `rbenv` with `'rehash'`, and so on...

And in your script all of these are interpreted as one arguments:

```
# Terminal:
su - user -c ls && echo 1
# Script
su - user -c 'ls && echo 1'
```

When all of this is said, it should be clear that your script is doing what it should do, but that `rbenv` is not in the `$PATH` set inside `su`. You can get around this by using the absolute path to `rbenv`:

```
su - xxx -c 'cd /home/xxx/apps/app_name && /path/to/rbenv ...'
```

A few things to note: Uppercase variable names are reserved to [environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), so you should consider using lowercase names. When you don't wrap [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) in double quotes they will undergo [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs).

Answer (score 1):

In your case the `su` command is applied only to the `cd` command.

Shell will split your command to following commands and evaluate each of them separately and use their return code to (partially) evaluate the `&&` expression:

```
su - xxx -c cd /home/xxx/apps/app_name
rbenv rehash
rbenv local 2.3.1
/home/xxx/apps/app_name/bin/unicorn -c /home/xxx/apps/app_name/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

So when we draw an evaluation tree, it will look like this:

```
shell
 `-- &&
     |-- su
     |   `-- shell
     |       `-- cd
     |-- rbenv
     |-- rbenv
     `-- unicorn
```

So to apply `su` to whole thing (as you want) wrap it in the quotes:

```
su - xxx -c 'cd /home... && rbenv ... && ...'
```

So when we draw an evaluation tree of the fixed command, it will look like this:

```
shell
 `-- su
     `-- shell
         `-- &&
             |-- cd
             |-- rbenv
             |-- rbenv
             `-- unicorn
```

Comment: Josef: Thank you for the suggestion but I still can't get it working. If I replace `$CMD` with `$CMD="'$SET_PATH && $UNICORN $UNICORN_OPTS'"`, I get :su - ... : No such file or directory`

Comment: That is another problem. In the script, you already had quoting done correctly, but the problem is in executing the `rbenv`. Check your $PATH and where the `rbenv` is: `whereis rbenv`, `echo "$PATH"` -- put these to the script and run them manualy, you should see the difference.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get this working. I have updated my original question with the adjusted script.

Comment: What is login shell of the user `$USER`? If it is not `bash` or `sh` it may be reason for this last trouble.

Comment: It is bash, so it shouldn't be causing the problem